# How can I simulate the LEA instruction with MOVE?

Tags: assembly, memory-address, mov, 68000, easy68k

How can I simulate the `LEA` instruction with MOVE? is this possible? I've used x86 assembly and the `MOV` instruction just copy adddress of if it's a symbol (not sure if it's assembly-dependent). But in 6800 `MOVE` looks like behave different, e.g., in the following instructions `D1` and `A1` has different values. How does `LEA` instruction work exactly? and how can I simulate? i.e., do what the `LEA` do without use it. I think that with `MOVE` and some others. Also, what does, de facto, `MOVE` is putting in `D1` it doesn't seem the hex values of label.

```
  MOVE T(PC),D1
  LEA T,A1
```

Comment: How about `MOVEA.L T,A1` ?

Comment: Nothing changed. Same behavior. Same values in registers: one different from other.

Comment: Oops. That should be `MOVEA.L #T,A1`. Or to put the address in a data register: `MOVE.L #T,D1` (note that `MOVE` affects some of the condition flags, while `MOVEA` and `LEA` don't).

Comment: Exactly it! you saved my day. Post it as anwer to I accept

Comment: Also, `MOVE` itself default to what? `MOVE.L` or `MOVE.W` or `MOVE.B`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an address register:

```
MOVEA.L #T,A<n>
```

For a data register:

```
MOVE.L #T,D<n>
```

Note that `MOVE` will update some of the condition flags, which neither `LEA` nor `MOVEA` does.

Comment: I will use `MOVEA` instead of. Thanks very much!